# Tips for visiting Disneyland Paris

Tags: budget, france, tips-and-tricks, disney

When you visit your local amusement park, you're often aware of how to get the best deal (cheapest visit).

Living in Denmark, going to Lego Land we always seem to know where you either get free tickets for the kids or atleast 50% off by buying stuff in a danish supermarked.

Once in Germany we managed to get cheaper tickets for Heide Park by buying some cold cuts for sandwiches.

I wonder if there is a smilair deal for Disneyland Paris? Also are there any other tips you could share if one wishes to visit Disneyland Paris and not wanting to spend a fortune going?

Comment: Parks likely intentionally use such deals as price discrimination in favor of locals, because they know the local going for a day is willing to pay less then someone travelling a long distance on vacation.  (However, that doesn't mean you can't take advantage, if you are able to find out how it works).

Comment: @dan1111 yep, this is my attempt at finding out, without doing a pre-tour to Paris (or France) ;)

Comment: I used to live near Disney World (U.S.) and there weren't any great deals for locals.  The best was a slightly lower rate on a 3 day pass for residents.  Disney is the top product in the market and so did not have to offer lots of deals to get people to come (I don't know if Disneyland Paris has a similar market position though).

Comment: The overwhelming tip is **don't go on Saturday**!  Disney Paris is fantastic, but don't go on Saturdays!

Answer (score 2):

If you search the web, you might be able to find deals up to 50% discount for Eurodisney. Usually, you will have to opt for a specific date. Sometimes, the deal is reserved to the local people but not always.

You can search websites like [ticketmaster](http://www.ticketmaster.fr).

Comment: Thanks, it's a bit hard to understand if you're not good at french - but it's worth a try :)

Comment: @PerHornshøj-Schierbeck There's the english version here: http://www.ticketmaster.fr/en/index Ticketmaster is just a ticket seller for events. No more no less.

Comment: Not sure if you'll find the same promotions on the english version. That's why I pointed out the French one. You can easily translate it via Google Translate :)

Comment: @Maurice it's usable, but when you use google translate, the javascript for the dates mess up. It's still ok. I can do one where i translate and understand and then one where i do it in french. Besides i did have 3 years french back in highschool so i ought to atleast get an idea ;)